# Column view in org-mode custom agenda command

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am trying to define a custom agenda view that includes two agenda commands:

- The first will list all unscheduled tasks with tag A (**using standard view**).
- The second will list all scheduled tasks with tag A (**using column view**, one column of which is the SCHEDULED timestamp).

The following code (code v1) works but does not include column view for the second agenda command:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("c" "My Custom View"
    ((tags-todo "TAGA"
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Unscheduled Tasks")
         (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled))))
     (tags-todo "TAGA"
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Scheduled Tasks")
         (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notscheduled))))
 ))))
```

I am trying to implement `org-agenda-view-columns-initially` in the second agenda command (code v2):

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("c" "My Custom View"
    ((tags-todo "TAGA"
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Unscheduled Tasks")
         (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled))))
     (tags-todo "TAGA"
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Scheduled Tasks")
         (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notscheduled))
         (org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%TODO %ITEM %SCHEDULED")
         (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)))
 ))))
```

When I evaluate code v2 and then open the custom agenda view, I get the same result as code v1. However, when applied to a single, simple command as described on [worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) and by [Carsten Dominik on the mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/10114), the result is as desired. I am also able to get column view for both scheduled and unscheduled results using code v1 and `C-c C-x C-c (org-columns)` but this is not my ideal outcome (I only want column view for the scheduled tasks).

Is this incorrect implementation on my part, or a limitation of `org-agenda-view-columns-initially`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A non-nil `org-agenda-view-columns-initially` will call `org-agenda-columns`, which unfortunately does not narrow to a region like `org-columns` does. So, if I'm not mistaken, the columnview applies to the whole agenda buffer, unless you rewrite the function.

Comment: Thanks @mutbuerger. I was hoping it would behave like `org-columns`.